# new element in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a piece of code that reads a csv-file into an multidimensional array, but at some point I want to add information to the array.

The persons array looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> array(2) {
    ["personnumber"]=> string(5) "test1"
    ["personname"]=> string(14) "Test person 1"
  }
  [1]=> array(2) {
    ["personnumber"]=> string(5) "test2"
    ["personname"]=> string(14) "Test person 2"
  }
  [2]=> array(2) {
    ["personnumber"]=> string(5) "test3"
    ["personname"]=> string(14) "Test person 3"
  }
  [3]=> array(2) {
    ["personnumber"]=> string(5) "test4"
    ["personname"]=> string(14) "Test person 4"
  }
}
```

I want to add a personid, making the array look like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> array(2) {
    ["personnumber"]=> string(5) "test1"
    ["personname"]=> string(14) "Test person 1"
    ["personid"]=> string(3) "453"
  }
  [1]=> array(2) {
    ["personnumber"]=> string(5) "test2"
    ["personname"]=> string(14) "Test person 2"
    ["personid"]=> string(3) "454"
  }
  [2]=> array(2) {
    ["personnumber"]=> string(5) "test3"
    ["personname"]=> string(14) "Test person 3"
    ["personid"]=> string(3) "455"
  }
  [3]=> array(2) {
    ["personnumber"]=> string(5) "test4"
    ["personname"]=> string(14) "Test person 4"
    ["personid"]=> string(3) "456"
  }
}
```

The personid comes from a database, I've constructed the code below to modify the persons array:

```
foreach ($persons as $row)
{
    $sql = "SELECT personid FROM persons WHERE person = '". $row['personname'] ."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $cell = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    $persons[$row]['personid'] = $cell['personid'];
}
```

When executed I get these errors:
Warning:  Illegal offset type in script.php on line X
Notice:  Undefined index:  personid in script.php on line X

What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried `array_push($persons[$row]['personid'], $cell['personid']);` but that doesn't work either.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the documentation?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

mysql_fetch_row returns an enumerated array (like it says in the first line of the documentation).
You would want to use either key 0 ($cell[0]) or mysql_fetch_assoc() instead to use $cell['personid'].

BTW: you would want to escape the data (name) you put in the query. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($persons as $key => $row)
{
    $sql = "SELECT personid FROM persons WHERE person = '". $row['personname'] ."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $cell = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    $persons[$key]['personid'] = $cell['personid'];
}
```